# Get real table name in Magento

Tags: zend-framework, magento

How to get magento table name dynamically?

I tried :

`Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read')->getTableName('catalog/product')`

returns `catalog/product`, when it should return `catalog_product`. How do I get real table name, as defined in `<table></table>` tags in config.xml?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

use instead :

```
echo Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('catalog/product');
```

outputs `catalog_product_entity`